# Missing confidence intervals complicate model predictions and plots

Tags: r, regression, prediction, non-linear-regression, sjplot

I am running a model where the response variable is proportion, inflated with a majority of 'zero'  and quite a few '1' responses, the terms of the model interact. I have therefore opted for a GALMSS model with family=BEINF.

The model coefficients seem reasonable, yet when I try to calculate or plot the marginal effects for the model I run into trouble. Based on the errors and warnings I receive I think this may be because there is no data for some levels of factors when used in certain interactions. Therefore some confidence intervals are NA.

I am looking for a way to work around this as I'd like to plot the marginal effects with use of confidence intervals, but am unsure how.

Below are my coding attempts, at the bottom of the post is dput for a reproducible example.

```
pr1 <- gamlss(Winproportion~Opponent:Age + Number_opps:Age, family=BEINF,data=pr1data,method=mixed())

summary(pr1, level=0.95)  #Model summary output
```

**Could not compute variance-covariance matrix of predictions. No confidence intervals are returned.**

```
confint(pr1, level=0.95)  #model confidence intervals
#Attempt to plot anyways
plot_model(pr1, type = "pred", terms = c("Number_opps","Age","Opponent"),dodge=0.5)
```

**Could not compute variance-covariance matrix of predictions. No confidence intervals are returned.**

I attempted to circumvent this using ggpredict, which did not work either

```
ggpredict(Winproportion,terms=c("Number_opps","Age","Opponent"),ci.lvl=0.95,what="mu")
```

But it returns the same 'Could not compute vcov ...'
Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)
library(gamlss.dist)
library(gamlss)
library(ggeffects)
```

CODE:

```
structure(list(Age = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Adult", "Child"), class = "factor"), 
    Number_opps = c(5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7, 7, 
    5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 
    6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 5, 
    6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 5, 5, 7, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 
    3, 7, 6, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 
    6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 7, 7, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
    3, 7, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 3, 3, 5, 7, 
    7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6, 7, 5, 4, 7, 5, 
    6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 
    6, 7, 3, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 
    4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 7, 5, 3, 4, 
    7, 5, 4, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 7, 1, 7, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 
    4, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 
    7, 3, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 
    6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 4, 7, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 3, 4, 7, 3, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 
    4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 
    5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 7, 7, 7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 
    7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 
    3, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 4, 
    4, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 7, 7, 2, 6, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 
    7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 7, 6, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 6, 6, 
    2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 6, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    6, 6, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 7, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 4, 
    7, 7, 7, 3, 4, 7, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 7, 
    7, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 7, 
    3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 
    7, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 3, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 
    5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 7, 6, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 5, 
    4, 5, 7, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
    3), Opponent = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Opp1", "Opp2", "Opp3", "Opp4", 
    "Opp5", "Opp6", "Opp7"), class = "factor"), Winproportion = c(0.365384615384615, 
    0, 0.0588235294117647, 0.133333333333333, 0.317307692307692, 
    0, 0, 0.285714285714286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.163934426229508, 
    0.109090909090909, 0.303370786516854, 0, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 
    0.142857142857143, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.263157894736842, 
    0, 0, 0.5, 0.428571428571429, 0, 0.230769230769231, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00892857142857143, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.201923076923077, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.448275862068966, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0454545454545455, 0.375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.5, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.196428571428571, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0444444444444444, 
    0, 0, 0.102564102564103, 0.444444444444444, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0689655172413793, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.233333333333333, 0, 0, 0.161290322580645, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0.125, 0.010989010989011, 
    0, 0, 0.438461538461538, 0.542857142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0.025, 
    0.243243243243243, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0232558139534884, 0, 0, 
    0.32258064516129, 0, 0, 0, 0.571428571428571, 0, 0.0288461538461538, 
    0.214285714285714, 0.0476190476190476, 0, 0, 0.258620689655172, 
    0, 0, 0.32, 0.0689655172413793, 0.103448275862069, 0.277777777777778, 
    0.673076923076923, 0, 0.125, 0.727272727272727, 0.375, 0.384615384615385, 
    0.26530612244898, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.444444444444444, 
    0.571428571428571, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.153846153846154, 0, 0, 
    0.037037037037037, 0.8, 1, 0, 0.703703703703704, 0.0294117647058824, 
    0, 0.0983606557377049, 0.0545454545454545, 0.177570093457944, 
    0.512820512820513, 0.296296296296296, 0.21875, 0.321428571428571, 
    0.385714285714286, 0, 0.516129032258065, 0.4, 0.5625, 0.0326086956521739, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.428571428571429, 0.444444444444444, 
    0, 0.358974358974359, 0, 0, 0, 0.26027397260274, 0.615384615384615, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0.375, 0, 0, 0.125, 
    0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.75, 0.105263157894737, 0.454545454545455, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.275862068965517, 0, 0, 0, 0.545454545454545, 
    0.647058823529412, 0.214285714285714, 0, 0.0303030303030303, 
    0, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 0.181818181818182, 0.866666666666667, 
    0.0357142857142857, 0.0731707317073171, 0.363636363636364, 
    0.592592592592593, 0.444444444444444, 0, 0.153846153846154, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.0858895705521472, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1875, 0.0909090909090909, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0151515151515152, 0.375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0232558139534884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0476190476190476, 0, 0.232142857142857, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.107142857142857, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.0714285714285714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152173913043478, 
    0.314285714285714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.234042553191489, 0, 0.0526315789473684, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0344827586206897, 0, 0.310344827586207, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0588235294117647, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.424242424242424, 
    0, 0, 0.0769230769230769, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.0526315789473684, 0, 0.25, 0.0659340659340659, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0571428571428571, 0, 0.5, 0.15, 0, 0, 0.025, 0.216216216216216, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.0454545454545455, 0.0434782608695652, 0, 0, 0, 0.355769230769231, 
    0, 0.529411764705882, 0, 0.144230769230769, 0.0714285714285714, 
    0.142857142857143, 0, 0.571428571428571, 0, 0.37037037037037, 
    1, 0, 0.0416666666666667, 0, 0, 0.181818181818182, 0, 0.523255813953488, 
    0.4, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 0, 0.5, 0.37037037037037, 0.104651162790698, 
    0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0.277777777777778, 0.176470588235294, 
    0.5, 0.411764705882353, 0.344262295081967, 0.254545454545455, 
    0.0654205607476635, 0.0769230769230769, 0.277777777777778, 
    0.53125, 0.285714285714286, 0.257142857142857, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.561797752808989, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 0.275, 0.0714285714285714, 
    0.285714285714286, 0.571428571428571, 0.688888888888889, 
    0.111111111111111, 0.263157894736842, 0.256410256410256, 
    0.555555555555556, 0.25, 0.285714285714286, 0.0625, 0.0526315789473684, 
    0.5, 0.153846153846154, 0, 0.3125, 0, 0, 0, 0.526315789473684, 
    0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.633333333333333, 
    0.645161290322581, 0, 0.5625, 0, 0.625, 0.0625, 0.153846153846154, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.122699386503067, 0.387096774193548, 0.176470588235294, 
    0, 0, 0.792452830188679, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0.357142857142857, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.396551724137931, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.375, 0, 0.285714285714286, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.307692307692308, 0.212121212121212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0.285714285714286, 
    0.2, 0, 0.0212765957446809, 0, 0, 1, 0.230769230769231, 0.0952380952380952, 
    0, 0.464285714285714, 0, 0.0833333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.764705882352941, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.434782608695652, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.375, 0.1875, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.196428571428571, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.4375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0512820512820513, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.304347826086957, 
    0.485714285714286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.458333333333333, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.714285714285714, 
    0.67741935483871, 0.51063829787234, 0, 0.105263157894737, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.857142857142857, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0344827586206897, 
    0, 0.344827586206897, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.230769230769231, 
    0.454545454545455, 0, 0, 0, 0.461538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0.195121951219512, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037037037037037, 0, 0, 0.105263157894737, 0.0289855072463768, 
    0.125, 0.21978021978022, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818181818182, 0.3, 
    0.238461538461538, 0.342857142857143, 0, 0.125, 0.7, 0, 0, 
    0.225, 0.135135135135135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.302325581395349, 
    0, 1, 0.931034482758621, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.0263157894736842, 0.0909090909090909, 
    0.130434782608696, 0, 0, 0.60655737704918, 0.0865384615384615, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.213114754098361)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 7L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 21L, 37L, 43L, 45L, 103L, 104L, 109L, 121L, 143L, 165L, 
166L, 197L, 198L, 203L, 209L, 210L, 215L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 
231L, 232L, 252L, 262L, 266L, 284L, 285L, 305L, 312L, 314L, 317L, 
320L, 321L, 329L, 352L, 353L, 355L, 361L, 370L, 383L, 396L, 410L, 
412L, 413L, 422L, 428L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 437L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 
445L, 449L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 457L, 458L, 461L, 462L, 464L, 466L, 
469L, 474L, 480L, 484L, 487L, 488L, 492L, 493L, 495L, 498L, 499L, 
500L, 501L, 502L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 
513L, 514L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 530L, 534L, 541L, 542L, 543L, 545L, 
547L, 549L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 564L, 566L, 572L, 573L, 575L, 
579L, 580L, 584L, 586L, 587L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 
596L, 597L, 601L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 618L, 619L, 621L, 624L, 628L, 
629L, 630L, 631L, 633L, 634L, 636L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 
652L, 653L, 659L, 660L, 662L, 664L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 
673L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 680L, 681L, 683L, 684L, 685L, 687L, 688L, 
693L, 698L, 699L, 700L, 705L, 706L, 717L, 726L, 727L, 732L, 733L, 
735L, 737L, 738L, 741L, 742L, 750L, 751L, 755L, 760L, 761L, 764L, 
771L, 773L, 774L, 776L, 778L, 782L, 786L, 787L, 790L, 791L, 795L, 
796L, 798L, 804L, 808L, 809L, 810L, 812L, 814L, 817L, 818L, 820L, 
830L, 831L, 832L, 833L, 835L, 837L, 838L, 854L, 856L, 858L, 863L, 
865L, 866L, 867L, 870L, 872L, 873L, 874L, 878L, 881L, 882L, 883L, 
892L, 902L, 903L, 904L, 909L, 913L, 914L, 916L, 924L, 926L, 928L, 
929L, 930L, 931L, 932L, 935L, 936L, 937L, 945L, 946L, 951L, 955L, 
956L, 963L, 966L, 994L, 1000L, 1007L, 1008L, 1013L, 1014L, 1015L, 
1016L, 1017L, 1018L, 1035L, 1042L, 1045L, 1056L, 1064L, 1065L, 
1066L, 1067L, 1068L, 1069L, 1070L, 1071L, 1073L, 1076L, 1077L, 
1083L, 1087L, 1094L, 1096L, 1097L, 1098L, 1104L, 1105L, 1106L, 
1109L, 1120L, 1121L, 1124L, 1125L, 1127L, 1133L, 1134L, 1135L, 
1137L, 1138L, 1139L, 1145L, 1147L, 1148L, 1153L, 1154L, 1156L, 
1159L, 1162L, 1163L, 1170L, 1171L, 1174L, 1176L, 1181L, 1185L, 
1186L, 1187L, 1188L, 1194L, 1195L, 1198L, 1199L, 1201L, 1212L, 
1216L, 1217L, 1225L, 1235L, 1236L, 1237L, 1238L, 1239L, 1249L, 
1250L, 1252L, 1254L, 1275L, 1277L, 1279L, 1284L, 1286L, 1287L, 
1288L, 1293L, 1294L, 1295L, 1299L, 1302L, 1303L, 1304L, 1310L, 
1311L, 1312L, 1313L, 1314L, 1315L, 1317L, 1318L, 1323L, 1324L, 
1325L, 1326L, 1329L, 1330L, 1334L, 1335L, 1336L, 1338L, 1341L, 
1342L, 1344L, 1345L, 1346L, 1347L, 1348L, 1349L, 1350L, 1351L, 
1352L, 1353L, 1354L, 1355L, 1356L, 1357L, 1358L, 1361L, 1363L, 
1365L, 1366L, 1369L, 1372L, 1376L, 1377L, 1383L, 1384L, 1387L, 
1389L, 1391L, 1393L, 1397L, 1398L, 1399L, 1400L, 1403L, 1404L, 
1407L, 1408L, 1411L, 1412L, 1413L, 1414L, 1415L, 1417L, 1420L, 
1426L, 1430L, 1432L, 1433L, 1434L, 1435L, 1436L, 1437L, 1438L, 
1439L, 1443L, 1445L, 1454L, 1456L, 1463L, 1466L, 1467L, 1468L, 
1470L, 1471L, 1475L, 1476L, 1477L, 1483L, 1485L, 1486L, 1487L, 
1488L, 1489L, 1490L, 1491L, 1492L, 1494L, 1495L, 1497L, 1498L, 
1501L, 1503L, 1504L, 1506L, 1508L, 1509L, 1516L, 1517L, 1518L, 
1519L, 1520L, 1522L, 1524L, 1526L, 1530L, 1532L, 1533L, 1534L, 
1539L, 1540L, 1541L, 1542L, 1543L, 1545L, 1546L, 1551L, 1552L, 
1553L, 1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1558L, 1559L, 1560L, 1566L, 1568L, 
1569L, 1570L, 1572L, 1573L, 1574L, 1575L, 1577L, 1579L, 1580L, 
1583L, 1584L, 1585L, 1591L, 1592L, 1594L, 1595L, 1602L, 1603L, 
1607L, 1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1612L, 1613L, 1615L, 1616L, 1619L, 
1620L, 1622L, 1625L, 1626L, 1627L, 1628L, 1629L, 1632L, 1633L, 
1634L, 1635L, 1636L, 1637L, 1638L, 1640L, 1641L, 1646L, 1649L, 
1650L, 1651L, 1652L, 1654L, 1656L, 1657L, 1658L, 1659L, 1660L, 
1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 1666L, 1670L, 1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 
1676L, 1677L, 1678L, 1679L, 1680L, 1684L, 1685L, 1687L, 1691L, 
1697L, 1698L, 1700L, 1705L, 1706L, 1721L, 1727L, 1729L, 1737L, 
1743L, 1750L, 1751L, 1761L, 1764L, 1768L, 1769L, 1770L, 1772L, 
1786L, 1787L, 1788L, 1793L, 1804L, 1805L, 1806L, 1810L, 1817L, 
1827L, 1836L, 1842L, 1843L, 1849L, 1850L, 1855L, 1856L, 1857L, 
1858L, 1859L, 1860L, 1864L, 1881L, 1882L, 1884L, 1887L, 1891L, 
1892L, 1893L, 1894L, 1899L, 1909L, 1910L, 1911L, 1912L, 1915L, 
1916L, 1922L, 1936L, 1944L, 1946L, 1947L, 1948L, 1950L, 1951L, 
1956L, 1961L, 1968L, 1969L, 1989L, 1996L, 1998L, 2001L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2013L, 2014L, 2024L, 2027L, 2036L, 2037L, 2045L, 2049L, 
2050L, 2067L, 2072L, 2073L, 2080L, 2094L, 2095L, 2096L, 2106L, 
2108L, 2109L, 2112L, 2117L, 2118L, 2119L, 2121L, 2126L, 2128L, 
2129L, 2130L, 2133L, 2134L, 2135L, 2136L, 2137L, 2141L, 2142L, 
2144L, 2145L, 2146L, 2150L, 2152L, 2153L, 2154L, 2155L, 2156L, 
2157L, 2161L, 2163L, 2164L, 2165L, 2166L, 2167L, 2168L, 2171L, 
2172L, 2176L, 2177L, 2178L, 2179L, 2180L, 2182L, 2183L, 2184L, 
2185L, 2186L, 2187L, 2188L, 2189L, 2190L, 2191L, 2192L, 2193L, 
2194L, 2195L, 2196L, 2197L, 2198L, 2199L, 2200L, 2203L, 2205L, 
2207L, 2208L, 2209L, 2212L, 2213L, 2214L, 2215L, 2216L, 2218L, 
2219L, 2225L, 2226L, 2229L, 2231L, 2233L, 2235L, 2239L, 2240L, 
2241L, 2242L, 2245L, 2246L, 2247L, 2248L, 2249L, 2250L, 2253L, 
2254L, 2255L, 2256L, 2257L, 2259L, 2262L, 2264L, 2268L, 2270L, 
2271L, 2272L, 2273L, 2274L, 2276L, 2277L, 2278L, 2279L, 2280L, 
2281L, 2285L, 2287L, 2288L, 2289L, 2296L, 2298L, 2302L, 2303L, 
2305L, 2308L, 2309L, 2310L, 2312L, 2313L, 2315L, 2317L, 2318L, 
2319L, 2325L, 2327L, 2328L, 2329L, 2330L, 2331L, 2332L, 2333L, 
2336L, 2337L, 2339L, 2340L, 2343L, 2344L, 2345L, 2346L, 2348L, 
2350L, 2351L, 2352L, 2353L, 2357L, 2358L, 2359L, 2360L, 2361L, 
2362L, 2364L, 2365L, 2366L, 2367L, 2368L, 2371L, 2372L, 2374L, 
2375L, 2376L, 2377L, 2381L, 2382L, 2383L, 2384L, 2385L, 2387L, 
2388L, 2389L, 2390L, 2393L, 2394L, 2395L, 2396L, 2397L, 2398L, 
2400L, 2401L, 2402L, 2406L, 2407L, 2408L, 2410L, 2411L, 2412L, 
2414L, 2415L, 2416L, 2417L, 2419L, 2421L, 2422L, 2425L, 2426L, 
2427L, 2433L, 2434L, 2435L, 2436L, 2437L, 2439L, 2444L, 2445L, 
2449L, 2450L, 2451L, 2452L, 2454L, 2455L, 2457L, 2458L, 2461L, 
2462L, 2464L, 2467L, 2468L, 2469L, 2470L, 2471L, 2474L, 2475L, 
2476L, 2477L, 2478L, 2479L, 2480L, 2482L, 2483L, 2488L, 2491L, 
2492L, 2493L, 2494L, 2496L, 2498L, 2499L, 2500L, 2501L, 2502L, 
2504L, 2505L, 2506L, 2507L, 2508L, 2509L, 2512L, 2513L, 2514L, 
2515L, 2517L, 2518L, 2519L, 2520L, 2521L, 2522L, 2526L, 2527L, 
2529L, 2530L, 2533L, 2538L, 2539L, 2540L, 2542L, 2547L, 2548L, 
2549L, 2550L, 2551L, 2554L, 2555L, 2556L, 2557L, 2558L, 2562L, 
2563L, 2565L, 2566L, 2567L, 2569L, 2571L, 2575L, 2576L, 2577L, 
2578L, 2579L, 2580L, 2581L, 2582L, 2584L, 2586L, 2587L, 2588L, 
2589L, 2592L, 2593L, 2597L, 2598L, 2600L, 2601L, 2606L, 2607L, 
2608L, 2610L, 2612L, 2613L, 2614L, 2615L, 2616L, 2617L, 2618L, 
2619L, 2620L, 2624L, 2625L, 2626L, 2629L, 2630L, 2633L, 2634L, 
2635L, 2636L, 2637L, 2639L, 2640L, 2646L, 2647L, 2648L, 2650L, 
2656L, 2660L, 2661L, 2662L, 2666L, 2667L, 2668L, 2669L, 2670L, 
2671L, 2674L, 2675L, 2940L, 2941L, 2947L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: 847 out of 1144 is a lot more than "almost half" zeros. I get an error with that data and code "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent".  I used the 'gamlss' and 'gamlss.dist' packages but your question had no `library` call so I might be using a different function.

Comment: I have copied the code again, perhaps I copy pasted wrongly. I've also added the libraries used.

Comment: I got the code to run and see the same error. I suspect that `sjPlot::plot_model` is not set up to handle interaction. I don't get the error and do get  shaded error bands when I make a model involving only main effects. Furthermore a model with only two interaction terms and no main effects is not going to be easy to explain to an audience. I'm not sure I can explain it to myself. (Is it even statistically sensible?)

Comment: @Vincent so there's no way to plot a confidence interval? Is this because of the certain interaction levels missing, and if so, is there no way to plot lines with confidence intervals for the interacting levels that are present? Does your plot_cap function take multiple terms (e.g. what you show, but one response curve per Opponent)?

Comment: @IRTFM thanks. I suppose that I could use full interactions (*) instead of ':' to ensure the presence of main effects. But that doesn't solve my problem of course.

Comment: @vincent Also, is there a possibility to plot what you plotted, but dropping the parts of the prediction for which there is no data (thus no CIs can be calculated)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [the development version of the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/), which can compute standard errors for predicted values using the delta method. (Disclaimer: I am the author.) Install it from Github:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")
```

Estimate the model:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(gamlss)

pr1data <- na.omit(pr1data)
pr1data <- subset(pr1data, !is.na(Age))
pr1 <- gamlss(
    Winproportion ~ Opponent:Age + Number_opps:Age,
    family = BEINF,
    data = pr1data,
    method = mixed())
```

Call the `predictions()` function and display the first 6 rows of the results:

```r
predictions(pr1, what = "mu") |> head()
#>   rowid     type predicted  std.error Winproportion Opponent   Age Number_opps
#> 1     1 response 0.2852127 0.06649437    0.07142857     Opp5 Adult           4
#> 2     2 response 0.2458822 0.05741226    0.14285714     Opp5 Adult           5
#> 3     3 response 0.2852127 0.06649437    0.00000000     Opp5 Adult           4
#> 4     4 response 0.1787867 0.04544875    0.11111111     Opp5 Adult           7
#> 5     5 response 0.1787867 0.04544875    0.26315789     Opp5 Adult           7
#> 6     6 response 0.2103789 0.05048144    0.00000000     Opp5 Adult           6
```

Obviously, you could then construct symmetric intervals as usual:

```r
predictions(pr1, what = "mu") |>
    transform(
        conf.low = predicted - 1.96 * std.error,
        conf.high = predicted + 1.96 * std.error) |>
    head()
#>   rowid     type predicted  std.error Winproportion Opponent   Age Number_opps
#> 1     1 response 0.2852127 0.06649437    0.07142857     Opp5 Adult           4
#> 2     2 response 0.2458822 0.05741226    0.14285714     Opp5 Adult           5
#> 3     3 response 0.2852127 0.06649437    0.00000000     Opp5 Adult           4
#> 4     4 response 0.1787867 0.04544875    0.11111111     Opp5 Adult           7
#> 5     5 response 0.1787867 0.04544875    0.26315789     Opp5 Adult           7
#> 6     6 response 0.2103789 0.05048144    0.00000000     Opp5 Adult           6
#>     conf.low conf.high
#> 1 0.15488379 0.4155417
#> 2 0.13335415 0.3584102
#> 3 0.15488379 0.4155417
#> 4 0.08970716 0.2678663
#> 5 0.08970716 0.2678663
#> 6 0.11143532 0.3093226
```

And you can make predictions for user-specified values of the regressors using the `datagrid()` function and the `newdata` argument. There are many examples in the vignette.

Finally, note that the `plot_cap()` function will only return confidence intervals when the model is linear, or when it is a model for which we can make predictions on the link function and then backtransform them. This is not the case here, but you can still do this:

```r
plot_cap(pr1, condition = "Number_opps", what = "mu")
```

[image]